# Text Hover Animation In HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I have the following code:

```css
z {
  color: #0563bb;
}

z:hover {
  transform: translate(0, -7px);
  box-shadow: 0px, 32px, 25px, -8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2),
}
```

```html
 <p>Hi there <z>This is the text that needs the hover animation</z>
```

Why doesn't the animation seem to work? Is it because its text or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What animation? The code written will be applied immediately without any transition or animation.

Comment: The box shadow value is also invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem there is you are using `transform` but not `transition`. This way the text jumps to the next state without an animation. This should fix your problem:

```css
z {
  color: #0563bb;
  display:inline-block;
  trasform: translate(0, 0);
  transition: all 0.8s linear;
}

z:hover {
  transform: translate(0, -7px);
  box-shadow: 0px 32px 25px -8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  transition: all 0.8s linear;
}
```

```html
<p>Hi there <z>This is the text that needs the hover animation</z></p>
```

You should also remove the comas from the `box-shadow` value.

Answer (score 1):

It just needs a block-style display, as in `display:inline-block;`
Additionally, I added a transition on the element for a little animation.

Note: Your box-shadow values were not valid. I corrected them, but take a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow

Thanks @evolutionxbox for the guidance and extra set of eyes

```css
z {
  color: #0563bb;
  display:inline-block;
  transition: transform .3s;
}

z:hover {
  transform: translate(0, -7px);
  box-shadow: 0px 32px 25px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
```

```html
<p>Hi there <z>This is the text that needs the hover animation</z></p>
```

Comment: The box shadow has an invalid property value. There's also still no animation?

Comment: Thanks @evolutionxbox for the guidance and extra set of eyes

Comment: Thank you for adding the animation.

Answer (score 1):

Your `box-shadow` property value is invalid. Remove the commas:

```css
z {
  color: #0563bb;
  display:inline-block;
}

z:hover {
  transform: translate(0, -7px);
  box-shadow: 0px 32px 25px -8px rgba(0, 0, 0)  /* percentage removed for demonstration */
}
```

```html
<p>Hi there <z>This is the text that needs the hover animation</z>
```

If you want to make the changes "animate", simply specify a transition duration:

```css
z {
  color: #0563bb;
  display:inline-block;
  transition:0.5s;
}

z:hover {
  transform: translate(0, -7px);
  box-shadow: 0px 32px 25px -8px rgba(0, 0, 0)  /* percentage removed for demonstration */
}
```

```html
<p>Hi there <z>This is the text that needs the hover animation</z>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no Element have name `<z>` in HTML, You Should not Put `,` in the last Line so The right Code in HTML mey be Lik eThis:

```
<p>Hi there <div class="z">This is the text that needs the hover animation</div></p>
```

and CSS Like This :

```
.z {
  color: red;
  display: inline-block;
 }

.z:hover {
  transform: translate(0, -7px);
  box-shadow: 0px, 32px, 25px, -8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
```

Or You should add Closing Tag For `p` Tag and Remove `,` in CSS Code and Replace it with `;`.
So Your Code Mey Be Like This:

```
<p>Hi there <z>This is the text that needs the hover animation<z></p>
```

and CSS Like This:

```
z {
  color: red;
  display: inline-block;
 }

z:hover {
  transform: translate(0, -7px);
  box-shadow: 0px, 32px, 25px, -8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
```

Comment: There's not a `z` element, but HTML is tolerant enough to allow it.

Comment: I know But I talk about the best syntax for his code.